# Database connection failed with JDBC to SAP Hana

Tags: jdbc, aws-glue

I'm currently trying to test a JDBC connection to SAP Hana with AWS Glue.

Testing the connection results in the following error message:

```
com.amazonaws.glue.jobexecutor.commands.exception.CommandExecutorException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.amazonaws.glue.jobexecutor.commands.jdbc.SupportedDriver.SAP
```

My JDBC URL looks like that `jdbc:sap://ip:port/?databaseName=tdb`

After looking in the [developer guide from AWS for the JDBC Connection Properties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-jdbc), it looks like that [required protocol for hana](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.03/en-US/ff15928cf5594d78b841fbbe649f04b4.html) is not a supported right now.

So is this the case that you currently can't connect to a SAP Hana database with AWS Glue or am I missing something in my connection configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HANA JDBC driver seems not to be supported at the moment. AWS describes a way via S3, that, depending on your requirements might be enough for you:

https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/awsforsap/extracting-data-from-sap-hana-using-aws-glue-and-jdbc/